# How do you name a static column group in a Reporting Services matrix report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can you (if at all) name a static column group in a SQL Server Reporting Services matrix report?  With 35 columns it gets a bit tricky when trying to match the generic (static) names with actual column headings.  I have not been able to determine via properties or other methods how to give these static column groups useful names.

See the attached image for a reference of what I mean.

[image: static column groups]

Answer (score 0):

Hey... This isn't an answer but this post doesn't have a place that I can just comment on the question.  Sorry, I don't know where else to put this.

What are you actually trying to accomplish by naming these columns?  You can name the text boxes.... and add expressions to those.... If you click on the "static" labels, it highlights the column heading for you... and all of my are always in order by default (might always be this way?).  But, what are you actually trying to do that those need names for?  I can't see a way to do it.

---

After I wrote that first comment down there in response to yours I decided to play with the code in one of my reports... It's still really hard without being able to actually name those columns but they are all in order at least, in the code.  For future editing to this report, I suggest adding comments in the code saying what each TablixMember actually is... But I don't think there is a way............... SSRS as a whole is sometimes very, very difficult and frustrating to use.  It drives me absolutely crazy but there aren't any other options that have enough benefits to use instead... and SSRS actually has a lot more functionality than some of its alternatives.

```
    <TablixColumnHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <Visibility>
            <Hidden>=iif(Parameters!hideCol1.Value is nothing, true, false)</Hidden>
          </Visibility>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
```

Comment: Clicking on a static member doesn't visually highlight the columns.  I have over 30 columns, all of which can be conditionally hidden/displayed, so for me naming them would eliminate the guess work of having to know which order they're in when trying to apply visibility expressions.

Comment: I don't think you can... but... you can name the actual text box?  Or you can just view the code and do it that way and do it all based on the content in the column and just type it in.  I would think that would be easiest...